# Proof that the sum of the order of the orbits of a set is = the order of the set?

Tags: group-theory, order-theory

I understand that the order of a set is the number of elements it has, however I don't understand the relationship between this number and the orbits of the set. As I understand it, the orbit of an element of a set is another set that contains all the images of that element, based on a group action where the elements of the set have some group action applied to them, using a group. So what happens if a set has 5 elements, and each element has exactly an orbit of 2? Then the total order of all the orbits is 10, but I know that this is not possible based on whatever theory this is called (is there a name for it?). But how do we know this is not possible?

Comment: Each element is in exactly one orbit. So if you add up the size of each of the orbits, you count each element exactly once.

Comment: How do you know that each element is only in exactly one orbit?

Comment: Adding on Daniel's answer: an action of a group on a set defines an **equivalence relation** on that set, and the orbits are the equivalence classes. Thus, each element of the set belongs to one and only one orbit, as Daniel points out, since the orbits thus are a *partition* of the set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are asking why the following result is true:

> Let $G,X$ be groups and let $G$ act on $X$. Then the sum of the orders
>   of the distinct orbits of $X$ in $G$ is the order of $X$. i.e.: $$\sum|\mbox{Orb}_{G}(x)|=|X|$$

This is true because the orbits of $X$ in $G$ *partition* the set $X$. That is, if we have two elements $x$ and $y$ whose orbits share some element $z$, then $\mbox{Orb}_{G}(x)=\mbox{Orb}_{G}(y)=\mbox{Orb}_{G}(z)$.

The proof is under the heading "transitivity" [here](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Orbit_is_Equivalence_Class#Transitivity).

Comment: This proves the comment by @mixedmath.

Comment: Thanks. I was told that the orbits partition the set, which means that all the orbits are disjoint. But what I didn't understand was how you know they are disjoint. i.e. How do you know that two orbits don't share one same element without the two orbits being equal to each other. But now I see that if two orbits share an element, the two orbits must be equal. Thanks again!